# Error:The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, android-studio

I had uninstalled an older version of Android Studio and installed the newer 2.2.3 version.
When I created a new project I got an error telling me it couldn't find the project.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: check you have given the correct path for your SDK 
app>press f4>SDK location

Comment: or simply check the given path for your new project is a valid one